# Porting JavaScript requestAnimFrame to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, porting, typescript

I'm currently stuck trying to port this code to TypeScript.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
      return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback){
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60, new Date().getTime());
      };
  })();
}
```

The tsc error I get is:

> supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

I've tried declaring an `interface WindowEx extends Window` containing the signatures, then casting to `(< WindowEx>window).xxx`, but I doubt this is the correct way to convert this "typical" code.

An attempt:

```
interface WindowEx extends Window {
  requestAnimFrame(callback, target?):number;
  webkitRequestAnimationFrame(callback, target?):number;
  mozRequestAnimationFrame(callback, target?):number;
  oRequestAnimationFrame(callback, target?):number;
  // msRequestAnimationFrame already at WindowAnimationTiming interface
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did to get your code to compile.  I just defined `requestAnimFrame()` as a global and typed it so that TypeScript could validate calls to it.  There's not any great way of extending built in types like `window` currently hence the need to do things like `(<any>window).webkitRequestAnimationFrame`.  As a general rule if the compiler complains and you know it's valid JavaScript you can always cast to `<any>` to make it work.

```
var requestAnimFrame: (callback: () => void) => void = (function(){ 
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
  (<any>window).webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
  (<any>window).mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
  (<any>window).oRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
  function(callback){ 
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60, new Date().getTime()); 
  }; 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the supplied parameters don't match the signature of call target is because you're calling a function like this:

```
(function(callback) { ... })();
```

That is, the function accepts `callback` but you aren't passing one in.

You should remove `callback` as a parameter because you're not using it anywhere in the function.